# Calculating probability of piecewise function

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, piecewise

I want to calculate the probability of a discrete random variable. First I defined the function:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{1/8, x == 1}, {2/8, x == 2}, {5/8, x == 3}}, 0];
```

Next I used the following:

```
Probability[x <= 2.1, x \[Distributed] pw]
```

But this doesn't return an answer, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pw` is not a probability distribution. Use

```
pw = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/8, 2/8, 5/8} -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

to get

```
Probability[x <= 2.1, x \[Distributed] pw]
```

> 3/8

Answer (score 3):

```
pw = Piecewise[{{1/8, x == 1}, {2/8, x == 2}, {5/8, x == 3}}, 0];
pd = ProbabilityDistribution[pw, {x, 0, Infinity, 1}];

Probability[x <= 2.1, x \[Distributed] pd]
```

> 0.375